# Space is not adding after word in textfield (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new in flutter, i have a textfield in my app and when i enter space then it is not added in the textfield.I have rapped my textfield and buttons with lhe ListTile...is this problem because of ListTile? if yes then what the alternative for ListTile or if it is not the case then what the exactly problem is??
My code is given below:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  TextEditingController _enterDataField = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("Read/Write"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(13.4),
            alignment: Alignment.center,

            child: new ListTile(
              title: new TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                controller: _enterDataField,

                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.message),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Write Something',
                ),
              ),

                subtitle: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    writeData(_enterDataField.text);
                  },

                  child: new Column(
                    children: [
                      new Text('Save Data'),
                      new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0)),
                      new FutureBuilder(
                      future: readData(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> data) {
                            if(data.hasData!=null)
                              {
                               return new Text(
                                   data.data.toString(),
                               style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                               );
                              }
                            else
                              {
                                return new Text('No Data Saved');
                              }
                      }

                      )],
                  ),
                )


            )
        ));
  }
}




Future<String?> get _localPath async
  {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async
  {
    final path =await _localPath;
    return new File('$path/data.txt');
  }

  Future<File> writeData(String? message) async
  {
    final file =await _localFile;
     return file.writeAsString('$message');
  }

  Future<String?> readData() async
  {
    try
    {
    final file =await _localFile;
    String? data = await file.readAsString();
    return data;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      return "Nothing Saved Yet!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Share more details for readData() and writeData().

Comment: @RohitChaursiya these are the future functions and i have added ...please check

Comment: please check the below code.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLength: null,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried to solve. check below code.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  TextEditingController _enterDataField = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("Read/Write"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(13.4),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ListTile(
                    title: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      controller: _enterDataField,
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.message),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Write Something',
                      ),
                      minLines: 1,
                      maxLines: 10,
                    ),
                    subtitle: TextButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        foregroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          writeData(_enterDataField.text);
                          readData();
                        });
                      },
                      child: new Text('Save Data'),
                    )),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0)),
                FutureBuilder(
                    future: readData(),
                    builder:
                        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String?> data) {
                      if (data.hasData != null) {
                        return new Text(
                          data.data.toString(),
                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return new Text('No Data Saved');
                      }
                    })
              ],
            )));
  }
}

Future<String?> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<File> get _localFile async {
  String path = await _localPath as String;

  return File('$path/data.txt');
}

Future<File> writeData(String? message) async {
  final file = await _localFile;
  return file.writeAsString('$message');
}

Future<String?> readData() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    String? data = await file.readAsString();
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return "Nothing Saved Yet!";
  }
}
```